# Empty value in json array, key gets dropped

Tags: php, json

I am using the following code to display an external API in json format.

```
<?php 
$result = file_get_contents('compress.zlib://https://URL', false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET'
        )
    )) 
); 

echo($result);
?>
```

The result is like:

```
{
    "product": [{
        "product_name": "paper",
        "product_no": "67",
        "price": "7"
    }, {
        "product_name": "pencil",
        "product_no": "69",
        "price": "5"
    }, etc]
}
```

However, if for example the value of the corresponding key "product_no" is empty, the key in that specific array is not visible anymore in json. I would like it to display "product_no":"", or something like that...

Comment: I really don't get you.. would you please elaborate?

Comment: not clear, you have already a json where `product_no` present. So how to check it is and modify??

Comment: That could be something to do with the provider, possibly not included in response by provider if it is empty.

Comment: Thank you Abassi. Although I have requested the provider of the API in question and they have indicated that the API returns key/value pairs in json even if the value is empty, I will check again.